# Why use virtual function instead of regular?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

In c++, the virtual function in base class can be overridden in derived class.
and a member function where the specific implementation will depend on the type of the object it is called upon, at run-time.

Since virtual function has to be implemented(except for pure virtual)
Can I use regular function in base class and redefine it in derived class?
if yes.
What's the point of using virtual function?

Thanks

Comment: You can *hide* a non-virtual function. That's generally a bad thing.

Comment: Are you sure its not given in your book ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine it but it won't work in a polymorphic way.

so if I have a

```
class base
{
   int foo(){ return 3; }
};

class Der : public base
{
  int foo() {return 5;}
};
```

and then have a function that takes a base

```
void dostuff(base &b)
{
   b.foo(); // This will call base.foo and return 3 no matter what
}
```

and I call it like this

```
Der D; 
dostuff(D);
```

Now if I change the base to

```
class base
{
   virtual int foo(){ return 3; }
};

void dostuff(base &b)
{
   b.foo(); // This will call the most derived version of foo 
            //which in this case will return 5
}
```

so the real answer is if you want to write common code that will call the correct function from the base it needs to be virtual.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Virtual function is base of object oriented language.
In java, all functions are virtual function.
But in c++, virtual function is slower than regular function.
So if there is no need to function override, you should use regular function instead of virtual function.